# Yocto build succeeds, but warning about missing RDEPENDS

Tags: yocto

I'm using Yocto to compile my application for my target hardware. *The build succeeds*, but I get a warning:

> WARNING: myApplication-0.0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/local/bin/myApplication contained in package myApplication requires libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.3), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_myApplication? [file-rdeps]

I've added everything I can find to both the DEPENDS and RDEPENDS of my application's recipe, but I'm still getting that error.

```
DEPENDS += "gcc-runtime"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++ libstdc++-dev gcc-runtime"
```

Is there something I can add to my RDEPENDS to eliminate this warning?

I have also tried these other combinations, all of which resulted in a successful build, and of which give the same warning.

- Both `DEPENDS` and `RDEPENDS` empty.
- `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++"`
- `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++ libstdc++-dev`
- `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++ gcc-runtime` `DEPENDS += "gcc-runtime"`

Comment: remove  libstdc++-dev and try

Comment: @Siva.V No change. See edit.

Comment: maybe try `libstdc++6` or `libstdc++-v3` ? Did you also try to clean all your build and sstate folders?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++6"
```

RDEPENDS needs the output package name which usually is the name of ipk or rpm and
not the recipe name which generated the given output package. Secondly packages containing only libraries also use debian library naming conventions so they get renamed like above.